# CMake issues with trying to include my source files

Tags: c++, cmake, sfml, clion

I am trying to use the CLion IDE on Linux and I am migrating my SFML application over. It insists I use CMake which I am currently having problems with.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(SFML2)


include_directories("${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR} src/")
include_directories("${YOUR_DIRECTORY} src")

# Define sources and executable
set(EXECUTABLE_NAME "SFML")
add_executable(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} src/SFML.cpp)


# Detect and add SFML
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake_modules"      
${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})

find_package(SFML 2 REQUIRED system window graphics network audio)
target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${SFML_LIBRARIES})

# Install target
install(TARGETS ${EXECUTABLE_NAME} DESTINATION bin)


# CPack packaging
include(InstallRequiredSystemLibraries)
```

However I keep getting build errors

```
CMakeFiles/SFML.dir/src/SFML.cpp.o: In function `main':
SFML.cpp:(.text+0xca): undefined reference to `Game::Game()'
SFML.cpp:(.text+0xd9): undefined reference to `Game::run()'
CMakeFiles/SFML.dir/src/SFML.cpp.o: In function `Game::~Game()':
SFML.cpp:(.text._ZN4GameD2Ev[_ZN4GameD5Ev]+0xa2): undefined reference to `Player::~Player()'
SFML.cpp:(.text._ZN4GameD2Ev[_ZN4GameD5Ev]+0xb4): undefined reference to `Player::~Player()'
SFML.cpp:(.text._ZN4GameD2Ev[_ZN4GameD5Ev]+0x18b): undefined reference to `Player::~Player()'
SFML.cpp:(.text._ZN4GameD2Ev[_ZN4GameD5Ev]+0x1a2): undefined reference to `Player::~Player()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/SFML.dir/build.make:90: recipe for target 'SFML' failed
make[2]: *** [SFML] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:60: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/SFML.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/SFML.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:136: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The Game reference is in the same location as the SFML.cpp, which is where everything is launched from.

This currently works without issue in Eclipse CDT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an update for anyone else whom might stumble across this problem. I edited these few lines into my code

```
# Define sources and executable
set(EXECUTABLE_NAME "SFML")

file(GLOB SRC
    "src/*.h"
    "src/*.cpp"
)

add_executable(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${SRC})
```

Seems to work now, can anyone confirm if this is the right way to do it?

Comment: The cmake documentation for `file(GLOB` suggests that it is not the right way: "We do not recommend using GLOB to collect a list of source files from your source tree. If no CMakeLists.txt file changes when a source is added or removed then the generated build system cannot know when to ask CMake to regenerate." - though I've seen it in several projects, and in practice it works fine (only developers are occasionally surprised when a simple `make` is not enough to build the project, after new files were added).

Comment: pherhaps this way you include more than one source file in the target? and the link errors go away...

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions

I'm not sure what are you intending to do with the include paths. My guess is that this is a left over from some experimentation. You've told CMake to look in 2 directories, both directories that have a space in them. Because you probably don't have a directory with a space in them, I think it can be deleted safely.

```
include_directories("${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR} src/")
include_directories("${YOUR_DIRECTORY} src")
```

I'm not sure where those variables are defined, but maybe you meant this

```
include_directories(src)
```

Second, CMake can use wildcards, but that is not the recommended method. You should explicitly list all source code files in the `add_exectuable()` call, ie.

```
 add_exectuable(${EXECUTABLE_NAME}
      src/SFML.cpp
      src/SFML.h
      src/other.cpp
      src/other.h
     # and so on
 )
```

Adding the header files is not required, but it makes it nice if you ever compile this with Visual Studio.

Comment: but his errors are from the linker... And If the entire project (the user part) consists of only one source file I see no way for Player to be undefined if this source used to build fine before moving to CLion/cmake...

Comment: His errors are from the linker, but the only difference is that before he had one source file, and after he had the same source file and all the other unmentioned names in the `src` folder. So there must be some source code that he needed from `src`.